# Ruby Sequel Subquery Happening Before Main Query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sequel

Can someone help me out with this?

I need the following sql code translated to sequel:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sales_leads.employee_person_id,
    (SELECT full_name from persons 
        WHERE sales_leads.employee_person_id=persons.id),
    (SELECT COUNT (sales_leads.id) from sales_leads 
        WHERE sales_leads.employee_person_id=employees.person_id 
        AND sales_leads.status='open') AS open_leads_count,
    (SELECT COUNT (sales_leads.id) from sales_leads 
        WHERE sales_leads.employee_person_id=employees.person_id 
        AND sales_leads.status='lost' OR sales_leads.status='won') AS closed_leads_count
FROM sales_leads
JOIN employees ON sales_leads.employee_person_id=employees.person_id
ORDER BY sales_leads.employee_person_id;
```

This is what I have so far:

```
DB[:sales_leads]
  .inner_join(:persons, id: :employee_person_id)
  .select(:full_name)
  .select_append(
    DB[:sales_leads]
      .select(:id)
      .where(Sequel[:sales_leads][:employee_person_id]=>Sequel[:persons][:id])
      .count
  ).all
```

But I am getting an error:

> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table
>   "persons" LINE 1: ...eads" WHERE ("sales_leads"."employee_person_id" =
>   "persons"....
>                                                                ^: SELECT count(*) AS "count" FROM "sales_leads" WHERE
>   ("sales_leads"."employee_person_id" = "persons"."id") LIMIT 1
>   Sequel::DatabaseError: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause
>   entry for table "persons" LINE 1: ...eads" WHERE
>   ("sales_leads"."employee_person_id" = "persons"....
>                                                                ^ from /home/john/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sequel-5.5.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:145:in
>   `async_exec'

Comment: you can also post the ruby ​​code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `Dataset#count` on the dataset you are passing to the select_append call, and `Dataset#count` runs a query.  You probably want `.select{count(sales_leads[:id])}` instead of `.count`.